# There has a bug with OpenAl or Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, openal

play sfx for loop on the scene:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("sfx_timesup.mp3", true);
```

set a bt to press play another sfx:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("sfx_bt.mp3", false);
```

it will stop the loop sfx after 31 times press bt.

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
USING_NS_CC;

CCScene* HelloWorld::scene(){
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();
    HelloWorld *layer = HelloWorld::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}
bool HelloWorld::init(){
    if ( !CCLayer::init() ) {
        return false;
    }
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("sfx_timesup.wav", true);

    CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    CCMenuItemImage *pCloseItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
                                        "CloseNormal.png",
                                        "CloseSelected.png",
                                        this,
                                        menu_selector(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback));
    pCloseItem->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/2 ,visibleSize.height/2));
    pCloseItem->setScale(10);
    CCMenu* pMenu = CCMenu::create(pCloseItem, NULL);
    pMenu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
    this->addChild(pMenu, 1);
    return true;
}
void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender){
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("sfx_bt.wav", false);
}
```

in the cocosdenshion.mm
this line :

```
int sourceIndex = [self _getSourceIndexForSourceGroup:sourceGroupId];
```

can't recognize the index whether loop or playing.

After 31 times click the bt. it will loop the sound channel and end the loop effect.

Comment: please post the actual code as text, not screenshots

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I need you help. I can't fix it. I post the simple code. it is cocos2dx 2.2.x least version. with templete.

Comment: There are 32 audio channels available. One is blocked by the mp3, so this sounds a lot like all channels are occupied and thus no new sound is played. Normally if a sound plays to end, the channel is freed again. And also normally, playing a new sound would simply interrupt one of the already playing sounds to prevent this precise problem. This could indicate a memory management problem, a problem with CD/channel setup/settings/priorities, and/or a problem with the audio files themselves (very long with lots of silence at the end?).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D it is wave file....

Comment: @LearnCocos2D now I find the solve way. I post it on my topic

Comment: you should post the solution as an answer, not embed it in your question

Answer (score 1):

At the end, I finally find the problem and fix it.

you need modify the init function in CDAudioManager.m file

add code:

```
[soundEngine setSourceGroupNonInterruptible:0 isNonInterruptible:TRUE];
```

after line:

```
soundEngine = [[CDSoundEngine alloc] init];
```

default cocos2d sound engine don't check with looping or playing sfx. Now it will do it. Why me  :< find so hard. Because game warning sfx stop strangely, and then find the sfx play problem, and then go into the black hole (sound engine) :< so sad...

Answer (score 0):

This bug is still there in cocos2d-x 3.8 and I've just run at this :) I have a better fix for this:

in CocosDension.m in function playSound add this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sourceTotal_; i++){
    ALint state;
    ALuint source = _sources[i].sourceId;
    alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    if (state != AL_PLAYING && state != AL_PAUSED) {
        sourceIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

between:

```
int sourceIndex = [self _getSourceIndexForSourceGroup:sourceGroupId];//This method ensures sourceIndex is valid
```

and:

```
if (sourceIndex != CD_NO_SOURCE) {
```

Comment: If next time it happen. I will try your code first.